# Zurb Foundation 5.5.2 range slider clicking on bar to advance handle to position does not work

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I am using Zurb Foundation 5.5.2 and trying to get the range slider to work like on the [Foundation web site documentation page for range sliders](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/range_slider.html).  The desired functionality is that you click on any location on the bar, and the handle advances to that location.  On the [Foundation web site kitchen sink page](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/kitchen_sink.html), clicking on the range slider bar does nothing.  On [this codepen](http://codepen.io/jrzerr/pen/EVWXbz) that I use the most basic range slider code, you also cannot click on the bar and get the handle to advance.  How do I get this to work?

Here is the Codepen code:

```
<div class="range-slider" data-slider>
  <span class="range-slider-handle" role="slider" tabindex="0"></span>
  <span class="range-slider-active-segment"></span>
  <input type="hidden">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foundation v5.x serie seems not trigger mousemove event when using slider. 
Digging into foudantion issues on github I found this:

[slider: add support for changing by clicking on the slider without having started to drag from the handle](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/pull/6695)

It strikes me that this feature is only available for future versions of Foundation library such as [v5.5.3](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/milestones/5.5.3) or [v5.6](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/milestones/5.6) (see milestones).

But you can use that rigth now, just copy and past o raw code from github:

- https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/js/foundation/foundation.js
- https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/js/foundation/foundation.slider.js

Just click on "raw" button and save to the local storage.
So it should be work like this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.2/css/foundation.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.2/js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-10 medium-11 columns">
        <!-- SLIDER START   -->
        <div class="range-slider" data-slider  data-options="display_selector: #sliderOutput3;trigger_input_change: true">
          <span class="range-slider-handle" role="slider" tabindex="0"></span>
          <span class="range-slider-active-segment"></span>
        </div>
        <!-- SLIDER END   -->
      </div>
      <div class="small-2 medium-1 columns">
        <span id="sliderOutput3"></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Foundation updated -->
    <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zurb/foundation/master/js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zurb/foundation/master/js/foundation/foundation.slider.js"></script>
    
    <script>$(document).foundation();</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @JeremyZerr That's nice! 
Just like I suspected